# using interchangeably these terms" to be / get used to

Tags: verbs

Dian has a new job. She has to get up much earlier now than before - at 6:30. She finds this difficult because she **isn't used to / doesn't get used to** getting up so early.

I am wondering if there is any difference between those?

What is more, could you think if a situation where both the following phrases could be interchangeable?-- although I know almost the difference between their meanings.

to be used to

get used to

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that you are used to something, it means that you are habituated or accustomed to it i.e. it's normal or usual to you. But if you say you'll get used to it, it means that you'll become accustomed to it i.e. it'll be no longer unusual, difficult for you with the passage of time. I am not used to this hot climate, but I'll soon get used to it.

I am (now) used to it can be replaced with "I have (now) got used to it".

Answer (score 1):

*To be used to* means *to be accustomed to*.

*To get used to* means *to become used to.*  If you are getting used to something, currently you are not used to it.

They are not interchangeable.

Thus the correct way to say the sentence is:

> Dian has a new job. She has to get up much earlier now than before - at 6:30. She finds this difficult because she isn't used to getting up so early.